# The Pythonic way of alternate looping over lists and dicts (combined)

Tags: python-3.x

Consider the two following variables:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = {
    'OK': [1, 3],
    'BAD': [2, 4]
}
```

Notice that the `1` in `a` is basically the same `1` in `b['OK']`.

**Note:** `a` may seem irrelevant, but it's there to keep the order of the items (which are **not** sortable, btw) as shown in the example below.

What's the most Pythonic way of looping over those two variable to effectively get those two results:

```
1: OK
2: BAD
3: OK
4: BAD
```

or

```
OK: 1
OK: 3
BAD: 2
BAD: 4
```

Here's the most straightforward way I could think of:

```py
if True:
    for i in a:
        for k,v in b.items():
            if i in v:
                do_stuff(i, k)
                break
else:
    for k,v in b.items():
        for i in v:
            do_stuff(k, i)
```

On the surface, it seems like those two are unrelated but I can't help but think there must be a better way that I'm missing here...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you even need `a` here?

Comment: When is `if True` false?? Will the `else` get executed in any way?

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear - `a` keeps the order of the output (which is **not** a sortable type btw). 
The `if True` is just to show that there's an if statement there. This is basically pseudo-code...

Comment: @wallace could you explain what you mean by *a keeps the order of the output (which is not a sortable type btw).*?

Comment: @JonClements Yes. The difference between the two outputs is the order in which they're shown. The first one is "sorted" by the order of the items in `a` and the second one is "sorted" by the order of the items in `b`.
I should've made `a = ['banana', 'apple', 'mango']` to make it clearer that the order of the items is important for the output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your starting point:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = {
    'OK': [1, 3],
    'BAD': [2, 4]
}
```

Create a lookup dict of key->position for efficient lookup:

```
order = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(a)}
```

Use a gen-exp to flatten out key and each value in list:

```
flattened = ((k, v) for k, lst in b.items() for v in lst)
```

Sort elements such that they're ordered by the priority in `a` (you might want to specify a default value to `.get` such as `float('-inf')` (will put non-found values before everything) or `float('inf')` (will put non-found values after everything) - if you're expecting a lookup to fail...):

```
res = sorted(flattened, key=lambda L: order.get(L[1]))
```

This gives you:

```
[('OK', 1), ('BAD', 2), ('OK', 3), ('BAD', 4)]
```

Comment: Very interesting thinking. I took your answer, modified it and checked it against the "naive" approach, and it's not too far behind in terms of speed! Here's a link to my test: https://repl.it/repls/ThankfulMixedField Thank you very much!

Comment: @wallace note that your code and the one above have different behaviour... For instance - try both with `b = {'OK': [1, 3], 'BAD': [2, 4], 'MEH': [1, 2]}`... I think the above gives the most reasonable answer but then what you've got could well be correct...(I'm not sure if there's constraints you've not mentioned that are applicable...)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. However, you were right - the idea was that the items in `a` and `b`'s values are exactly the same. `a` essentially acts as an indexer for one of the cases.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
for k,v in b.items(): 
    for elem in v: 
        if elem in a:
            print('{}:{}'.format(elem,k))
```

This is assuming that the two elements printed result should contain all the elements in `a`. If that's not the case, then simply remove `if` statement and your code just uses the variable `b`.

Like this:

```
for k,v in b.items(): 
    for elem in v: 
        print('{}:{}'.format(elem,k))
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear - the idea of the first output was to keep the order of the items in `a`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need the if else statement...
Your method seems to work without it

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = {
    'OK': [1, 3],
    'BAD': [2, 4]
}

for num in a:
    for key, value_list in b.items():
        if num in value_list:
            print("{0}: {1}".format(key, num))
```

outputs

```
OK: 1
BAD: 2
OK: 3
BAD: 4
```

To get your second output you can use the following

```
for key, value_list in b.items():
    for value in value_list:
        print("{0}: {1}".format(key, value))
```

which would not use `a` at all and would give

```
OK: 1
OK: 3
BAD: 2
BAD: 4
```

however if `a` were in a different order and you wanted the output within groups to be in that order you could use

```
a = [3, 2, 4, 1]
b = {
    'OK': [1, 3],
    'BAD': [2, 4]
}

for key, value_list in b.items():
    for num in a:
        if num in value_list:
            print("{0}: {1}".format(key, num))
```

Which would output

```
OK: 3
OK: 1
BAD: 2
BAD: 4
```

Alternatively you could make a list with entries such as `{1:'OK'}`

```
c = [{1:'OK'}, {2:'BAD'}, {3:'OK'}, {4:'BAD'}]

for elem in c:
    print(elem)

print("or")

for elem in c:
    for key, value in elem.items():
        print("{0}: {1}".format(key, value))
```

output

```
{1: 'OK'}
{2: 'BAD'}
{3: 'OK'}
{4: 'BAD'}
or
1: OK
2: BAD
3: OK
4: BAD
```

Comment: I have realized what your if else statement was for and that my solutions mirror yours. This does look like the most pythonic way to do this to me. Although it may not be the most efficient

Comment: Hey, thanks for trying to help! I'm struggling to accept the fact that I have to repeat myself in a Pythonic code :(